# Android view dithering

Tags: android, user-interface, dithering

As you can see from the screenshot below, the "titlebar" is getting these ugly banding lines across the areas with text that extend the entire width of the screen. It's even more noticeable on a real device.

Is there any way to work around this?

[image: activity]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Android Developers: Widget Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html):

> In some cases, devices have low pixel
>   depths that can cause visual banding
>   and dithering issues. To solve this,
>   application developers should pass
>   assets through a "proxy" drawable
>   defined as XML:. This technique
>   references the original artwork, in
>   this case "background.9.png", and
>   instructs the device to dither it as
>   needed.

**EDIT:**
Example source. This is an xml file in your `res/drawables` directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/title_bar_medium"
    android:dither="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I added some example code to your answer, for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:tileMode="repeat"` in this code, like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/b1"
    android:tileMode="repeat"
    android:dither="true" />
```

Reason is, on some devices it still stretches the image and it looks pretty bad, check this 
[Reference here](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=247)