# Apply Style to Android ListView

Tags: android, styles, android-listview

I want to style the lisview in my application as seen is this image

[image: Expected Output]

I have tried to develop it by applying gradient :

code for list_item_normal is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:centerColor="#E6E6E6"
        android:endColor="#CCCCCC"
        android:startColor="#FFFFFF" 
        android:angle="270"/>
    <!--
        <gradient
        android:startColor="#FF7500"
        android:centerColor="#FFCC00"
        android:endColor="#FF7500"
        android:angle="270"/>
    -->

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#A0000000" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="8dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="8dp" />

    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

code for list_item_pressed.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:centerColor="#E6E6E6"
        android:endColor="#CCCCCC"
        android:startColor="#FFFFFF" android:angle="270"/>
    <!--
         <gradient android:startColor="#FF66CFE6" android:centerColor="#FF207FB9" 
        android:endColor="#FF0060B8" android:angle="270"/>
    -->

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#80000000" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="8dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="8dp" />

    <corners android:radius="7dp" />

</shape>
```

code for list_item_pressed.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:centerColor="#E6E6E6"
        android:endColor="#CCCCCC"
        android:startColor="#FFFFFF" android:angle="270"/>
    <!--
         <gradient android:startColor="#FF66CFE6" android:centerColor="#FF207FB9" 
        android:endColor="#FF0060B8" android:angle="270"/>
    -->

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#80000000" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="8dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="8dp" />

    <corners android:radius="7dp" />

</shape>
```

and list_gradient.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_pressed" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_selected" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_normal" />

</selector>
```

and i have applied this style on `custom listitem` like :

```
<TextView
    .../>

<ImageView
   ... />
```

and the main.xml in which i have lisview is :

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/List"
    style="@style/list_item_gradient"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="true" >
</ListView>
```

and i am getting output as shown below :

[image: current output]

Please help me by telling what i am doing wrong..

Thanks
Shruti

Comment: I was trying to get my hands dirty with custom layouts of list row. I did what was necessary like pressed state, selected state, and normal state (like mentioned in your drawable files). I also changed the default layout style to list_item_gradient. I am running into choreographer warnings that I may be doing too much work on main thread. What could be a possible work around for this?

Comment: try using Async Task,to reduce work on main thread.

Comment: I also read on some forums that it is because the style doesn't have any parent attribute. How to define one?

Comment: I'm not sure whether to use AsyncTask here as I'm not doing any network related or any other heavy operation. Do you have any links which I can look into to solve this issue?
Here is the blog post http://thesoftwarerogue.blogspot.in/2010/12/skipping-entry-in-package-table-0.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you know about Dithering? Check this: http://android.amberfog.com/?p=247.

Also check these questions:

1. [How to draw a smooth/dithered gradient on a canvas in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936803/how-to-draw-a-smooth-dithered-gradient-on-a-canvas-in-android)
2. [Android view dithering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210976/android-view-dithering)

And yes, i would suggest to create custom adapter for your LitsView, in which you just have to create one custom row xml layout file and apply the background image for one time.

Comment: please explain it a bit more..do i need to add listselector ??

Comment: i hav created a custom adapter only thing that is not wrking for me is i am unable to change the color of selected listitem

Comment: @DroidShruti i think you are talking about that "yellow" image appears while touching a particular listitem, right? if this is the case then create selector.xml and apply it.

Comment: yes i was talking about that only .. thanks fr replying .. created a selector and it is working fine

Comment: @DroidShruti i am glad that my answer is helpful to you :)

Comment: @DroidShruti I'm in love with you.. <3

Answer (score 1):

create a `customAdapter` extends `baseAdapter` . create list_item.xml and give it desired look set selector to its background .
thats it .

Comment: i have creted a custom adapter the only issue i am having is while selecting a list item its color doesnot change as shown in the first image