# Background-color select (dropdown) on Android (opera, chrome)

Tags: android, css, smartphone

I want to set the background-color of specific options in a select menu.

On the desktop browsers it works fine, but when i look on my smartphone (android with chrome) no background-color is shown up.

I do it like:

```
<select>
   <options></options>
   <options class="color"></options>
   <options></options>
 </select
```

and style it:

```
.color{background-color : #999;}
```

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Hi, why is your css declaration inserting **#999**  inside quotation mark ?

Comment: Sorry, i write it the wrong way...But that was not the problem. Iphone  and Android show their own selectmenu on a website. But can i change the background color of this menu?

Comment: Check those : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558172/apply-style-to-android-listview

Comment: Could this help you : http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-part-2 ?

Answer (score 0):

What i see is INVALID css formating.

Try removing quotation mark for color declaration

```
.color{background-color : #999;}
```

For a last try,

```
.color{background-color : #999!important;}
```

Could this help you : http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-part-2 ? Actually, there is not enough information on you context to figure out what's happening. ( DOCTYPE, css stack order, html validation, etc )

I am not sure if you want to stylize a `<select>` or a `<list view>`

Comment: See answer above, sorry for my mistake.